# options nvidia-drm modeset=1 in place but still have the modeset error

Tags: nvidia, drm

I've read this [[SOLVED] cannot set nvidia-drm.modset=1](https://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?p=743148), and this [nvidia-drm Failed to grab modeset ownership](https://%5BDual%20system,%20Ubuntu%2020.04%5Dnvidia-gpu:%20i2c%20timeout%20error;%20ucsi_ccg:%20i2c_transfer%20failed%20-110,%20ucsi_ccg_init%20failed), and this [[Dual system, Ubuntu 20.04]nvidia-gpu: i2c timeout error; ucsi_ccg: i2c_transfer failed -110, ucsi_ccg_init failed](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+question/706349) and many others.  The first article says to "edit `/etc/modprobe.d/nvidia.conf` or `/etc/modprobe.d/nvidia-kernel-common.conf`" and add the line `options nvidia-drm modeset=1`.  I don't have either of those files but there is an `/etc/modprobe.d/nvidia-graphics-drivers-kms.conf` which already has that line present:

```
# This file was generated by nvidia-driver-535
# Set value to 0 to disable modesetting
options nvidia-drm modeset=1
```

Yet, I continue to get the drm error in `dmesg`:

```
[   17.478652] [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000900] Failed to grab modeset ownership
[   20.149255] systemd-journald[572]: File /var/log/journal/10b971ac1a304176906b1f6a23827476/user-1000.journal corrupted or uncleanly shut down, renaming and replacing.
[   20.706536] [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000900] Failed to grab modeset ownership
```

What I don't know is how much of an issue this is.  I'm am investigating an infrequent failure to resume from suspend issue so, while I'd like to get rid of this message, it would be helpful to know if this error might be related to the issue resume issue.